# How To Get Fork on Chain Repositories With Composer

Tags: git, github, repository, composer-php, git-fork

[image]

composer update doesn't get my forked repository.

**my project composer.json**

```
"require": {
    "github/repo-1": "^0.3.8",
},
"repositories": [{
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/personal/repo-1"
    },
],
```

**my forked repo-1 composer.json**

```
"require": {
    "github/repo-2": "^0.1",
},
"repositories": [{
    "type": "vcs",
    "url": "https://github.com/personal/repo-2"
}],
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I don't get any error, just pulling original repository.I don't get forked repos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should use as **dev-master**

```
"require": {
  "github/repo-1": "dev-master",
  "github/repo-2": "dev-master",
},
"repositories": [{
    "type": "vcs",
    "url": "https://github.com/personal/repo-1"
},
{
     "type": "vcs",
     "url": "https://github.com/personal/repo-2"
}],
```

**OR
some situation**

```
"require": {
  "github/repo-1": "dev-master as v1.1.x-dev",
  "github/repo-2": "dev-master as v2.1.x-dev",
},
"repositories": [{
    "type": "vcs",
    "url": "https://github.com/personal/repo-1"
},
{
     "type": "vcs",
     "url": "https://github.com/personal/repo-2"
}],
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the repos of which you need the forks in the main composer.json and require the chained dependency explicitly.

**my project composer.json**

```
"require": {
  "github/repo-1": "^0.3.8",
  "github/repo-2": "^0.1",
},
"repositories": [{
    "type": "vcs",
    "url": "https://github.com/personal/repo-1"
},
{
     "type": "vcs",
     "url": "https://github.com/personal/repo-2"
}],
```

Then run:

```
composer update github/repo-1 github/repo-2
```